# Differentiating quantum mechanics and string theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, string-theory

It was surprising to learn how difficult it is classify a theory as classical or quantum based on criteria (PDE, complex numbers, axioms, probabilities, Planck constant, and realism). Rreference, “What makes a Theory Quantum”, ([What makes a theory "Quantum"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/397694/what-makes-a-theory-quantum)).
My question, if String Theory were included in the comparison, how would the criteria differ and would there be a clear distinction? Thanks

Comment: There isn't much of an issue classifying string theory as quantum since it uses the same formalism as every other quantum theory, path integrals and Hilbert spaces.

Comment: People doing loop quantum gravity call what they do a type of "canonical" quantum gravity, which I guess lays their claim to be doing the only natural generalization of quantum mechanics to include gravity. Of course I'm sure string theorists would disagree.

Comment: The distinction between quantum and classical is very subtle, especially in string theory since there are, in a sense, two $\hbar$s: the string length squared, $\ell_s^2=\alpha'$, (which is the $\hbar$ of the 2d theory) and the string coupling constant, $g_s=e^{\Phi}$, with $\Phi$ the dilaton (which is the $\hbar$ in the spacetime theory).  Furthermore, string dualities mix these two in surprising ways. E.g., summing string loops (all powers of $g_s$) can lead to a theory that looks classical from a spacetime viewpoint.

Comment: Some related comments can be found in the popular science article: https://www.sns.ias.edu/ckfinder/userfiles/files/Reflections(3).pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reference, which introduces string tension as a new fundamental constant analogous to the Planck constant. The new constant implies quantum mechanics (if I correctly understood Witten’s article).  I was initially thinking that there might a “branch” of math or criteria which is unique to String Theory. This constant may be the key mathematical distinction.