# The Field $\mathbb{F}$ of A Hilbert Space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, vectors, complex-numbers

Is it always necessary for the field of some arbitrary Hilbert space I define to describe a system be a field of complex numbers only?
Is it possible to have a field of naturals, or reals?

Since the vectors in the Hilbert space can be whatever I want (if I follow the two-three rules), I was wondering if the definition is agnostic to the elements in the field as well.

Comment: The naturals isn't a field. As for the why not reals, I suggest reading this https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32422/ as it has already been asked there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QM without complex numbers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32422/)