# Complex numbers in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, complex-numbers

Are complex numbers used in the way the are in quantum mechanics for convenience sake? Or are they fundamental to quantum mechanics. In other words can quantum mechanics be completely described without the use of complex numbers?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32422/2451 and links therein.

Comment: See also [these](https://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec9.html) [links](https://scottaaronson.blog/?p=4021), written by Scott Aaronson.

Comment: See also the recent Renou MO, Trillo D, Weilenmann M, Le TP, Tavakoli A, Gisin N, Acín A, Navascués M. Quantum theory based on real numbers can be experimentally falsified. Nature. 2021 Dec 23;600(7890):625-9.  https://doi.org/10.1038/s41586-021-04160-4